# Why does PyCharm index directories outside of project root?

Tags: indexing, pycharm

I created a new virtualenv on the shell in this directory:

/home/x/projects/foo-env

Then I started PyCharm and opened above directory as new project.

Since PyCharm took very long to index above empty virtualenv I looked at the process:

```
ls -l /proc/PID-OF-PYCHARM/fd
....
lr-x------ 1 x x 64 Aug 22 13:02 29 -> /home/x/Musik/Hit-Giganten/Best_Of_Italo_Hits/cd1/08.Adriano_Celentano__24.000_Baci.ogg
```

Why does PyCharm look at my folder containing Italian pop-music?

I googled, but could only find a way how to exclude directories which are in the project root. Above file is outside the project root.

Comment: Can you show what you have inside _External Libraries_ in project structure?

Comment: @mx0 sorry, I don't see "external libraries" under "project structure". How can I show you the neede information?

Comment: In left panel below project structure should be External Libraries (https://imgur.com/a/jfgd5fQ). What directories are listed there?

Comment: Can you check solution from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001339380--SOLVED-Why-PyCharm-is-scanning-my-Home-folder?

Comment: @guettli, as @mx0 pointed out this means you have some interpreter settings added which is scanning this. PyCharm is not doing it by mistake, you have a config which is doing it. Baes on your pycharm version, you can go to "~/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2019.2" (if Mac) and do `grep -ri /home/x .` to check where all you have used home paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings->Project->Project interpreter->Click on the settings icon button->Remove the path of the directory that you don't want to be included.

Found the solution at:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000550410-Constant-indexing-of-external-data-folder-makes-pycharm-unusable

Comment: The solution works, the GUI however has changed since. There is actual documentation at [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html).

Comment: In my case, PyCharm added my home directory as an interpreter path (source root?). I still wonder, why?